# How to deploy Nuxt.js in SPA mode on server properly?

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, vue.js, nuxt.js

I use Nuxt.js in **SPA mode** in my project. But I can't properly deploy it in my server (Apache). Has anyone had that experience?

I think that the problem is in trailing slash in URL tried to set DirectorySlash Off in my .htaccess, but then it just doesn't work.
Also tried

Does not help as well:

```
DirectorySlash Off

#removing trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST_FILENAME}  /(.*)/( |$|?)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

# internally add the slash back
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L]
```

My project is on http://4dea.ru/works/TEST/spc/ now. If you push the button (in the section with the picture of the man on the boat on background) you will go to http://4dea.ru/works/TEST/spc/morskie-konstrukcii and everything works fine. But if you refresh the page, some pictures are missing (in the header, for example).

On the local server (Node.js) everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out two ways to do that:
1. Instead of `href="image.png"` use `href="/image.png"`, so the path to the image will be absolute and accessible from every page. But this option doesn't work if the app is not located in the root directory (like in my case).
2. Load images from assets folder via `href="@/assets/image.png"`. For styles and dynamic paths ``` :style="{backgroundImage: ``url('${require('@/assets/boat.jpg')}')``}" ``` can be used.

Hope it helps you ^^